# Cómo eliminar la advertencia -> SQLite warning (284): automatic index on

Tags: c#, sqlite

Estoy haciendo la sigiente consulta en una base de datos SQLite

```
            "INSERT INTO TRADES(ID,PASS,TIME_IN,TICKET,TYPE,VOLUME,SYMBOL,PRICE_IN,TIME_OUT,PRICE_OUT,COMMISSION,SWAP,PROFIT) " +
            "SELECT " +
            "   d1.id as id," +
            "   -1," + 
            "   d1.time as time_in," + 
            "   d1.position_id as ticket," +
            "   d1.type as type," +
            "   d1.volume as volume," +
            "   d1.symbol as symbol," + 
            "   d1.price as price_in," +
            "   d2.time as time_out," +
            "   d2.price as price_out," +
            "   d1.commission+d2.commission as commission," +
            "   d2.swap as swap," +
            "   d2.profit as profit " +
            "FROM DEALS  d1 " +
            "INNER JOIN DEALS d2 ON d1.position_id=d2.position_id  " +
            "WHERE d1.entry=0 AND d2.entry=1 AND d1.id=d2.id  ;",
```

Y estoy obteniendo la siguiente advertencia.
**SQLite warning (284): automatic index on DEALS(ENTRY)**

Decir que el código funciona, lo he probado usando C++ y no tuve advertencias ni problemas.
Ahora lo estoy probando con C# y también funciona, pero me está dando dicha advertencia.

Estoy usando esta libreria de C# **System.Data.SQLite**

He buscado el los [codigos de error de SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html) y dice lo siguiente.

> (284) SQLITE_WARNING_AUTOINDEX El código de resultado
> SQLITE_WARNING_AUTOINDEX se pasa a la devolución de llamada de
> sqlite3_log () siempre que se utiliza la indexación automática . Esto
> puede servir como una advertencia a los diseñadores de aplicaciones de
> que la base de datos podría beneficiarse de índices adicionales.

La tabla DEALS tiene las siguentes columnas. Hasta donde yo sé la columna ENTRY no tiene ningna propiedad de autoindexado automático.

```
    "ID                  CHAR(50)," +
    "DEAL_ID     INT     NOT NULL," +
    "ORDER_ID    INT     NOT NULL," +
    "POSITION_ID INT     NOT NULL," +
    "TIME        INT     NOT NULL," +
    "TYPE        INT     NOT NULL," +
    "ENTRY       INT     NOT NULL," +
    "SYMBOL      CHAR(10)," +
    "VOLUME      REAL   NOT NULL," +
    "PRICE       REAL   NOT NULL," +
    "PROFIT      REAL   NOT NULL," +
    "SWAP        REAL   NOT NULL," +
    "COMMISSION  REAL   NOT NULL," +
    "MAGIC       INT    NOT NULL," +
    "REASON      INT    NOT NULL"
```

No sé por qué me sale esta advertencia y me gustaría que no me saliera. Sabe alguien por qué sale y/o cómo hacer para que no salga?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Lo que MySQL te está diciendo es: *"En esta query, estoy creando un índice automáticamente **porque tú no tienes uno configurado en la tabla**"*. Intenta utilizar EXPLAIN, o la herramienta en el Workbench para evaluar el rendimiento de la query y crear los índices sugeridos. Cuál es la solución? Crear el índice que MySQL está creando automáticamente.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por tu respuesta Ariel!!